# I am trying to import views.py to urls.py using (from . import views)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, pycharm

i created a python file in myapp and named it urls.py It looks like

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("", views.home),
    path("predict/", views.predict),
    path("predict/result", views.result)
```

Also I edited The project's urls.py as instructed an it now looks like

```
  from django import views
  from django.contrib import admin
  from django.urls import path


urlpatterns = [
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  path("", views.home),
  path("predict/", views.predict),
  path("predict/result", views.result)
```

The views.py in myapp looks like

```
def result(request):
data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\MAX\diabetes.csv")
X = data.drop("Outcome", axis=1)
Y = data['Outcome']
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2)

model = LogisticRegression(max_iter=1000)
model.fit(X_train, Y_train)

val1 = float(request.Get['n1'])
val2 = float(request.Get['n2'])
val3 = float(request.Get['n3'])
val4 = float(request.Get['n4'])
val5 = float(request.Get['n5'])
val6 = float(request.Get['n6'])
val7 = float(request.Get['n7'])
val8 = float(request.Get['n8'])

pared = model.predict([[val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6, val7, val8,]])

result1 = ""
if pared == [1]:
    result1 = "positive"
elif pared == [0]:
    result1 = 'negative'
return render(request, "predict", {"result": result1})
```

Also I added myapp in the list of installed apps in my project's settings.py

Comment: Please, provide the whole error/traceback as formatted text. And your project structure

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Diabetes Prediction\Diabetes_Prediction\Diabetes_Prediction\urls.py", line 19, in <module>
    from . import views
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: Please, [edit] your question to include the traceback as ***formated*** text and project structure as ***formatted*** text.

Comment: please what is your project name and app name? you're clearly mixing up something which is quite common with django beginners

Comment: My project name is Diabetes Prediction and my app name is Diabetes_Prediction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up your project level urls.py with your app urls.py. Your project urls.py is found in the directory containing your settings.py. It should look like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('myapp.urls')),
]
```

Your app urls.py should be created in your app directory i.e. where you have your views and models. Create a file named urls.py in that directory. It should look like this:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'myapp'
urlpatterns = [
    path(" ", views.home),
    path("predict/", views.predict),
    path("predict/result", views.result)
```

OP did not write app name in settings.py. Include your app name in settings.py as shown below:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # Default apps
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # My apps
    'myapp',     
]
```

**Please read as you seem to be mixing up a lot of things. Also read the docs I included** A typical Django project is made up of one or more apps. You create your project using the command `django-admin startproject your_project_name .` and you create your app using the following command `python manage.py startapp your_app_name`. Please make sure you're not mixing up both. Also make sure you included your appname in `INSTALLED_APPS` list in your `settings.py` See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/intro/tutorial01/) for more.

Comment: still getting an attempted relative import with no known parent package error

Comment: did you include your app name in your settings.py? can you show your settings.py, and your apps urls.py?

Comment: the settings.py looks like:

Comment: I can't see anything. Please not all settings.py.... just the INSTALLED_APPS list

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS =  [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

Comment: you did not include your app name in the INSTALLED_APPS list. I will edit my answer to show you how to do that. You said your app name is `Diabetes_Prediction` and project name is `Diabetes_Prediction`? Please make sure you're not confusing both.

Comment: Show me the lines in your settings.py enclosed in """ """. It should be at the top of your settings.py

Comment: Django settings for Diabetes_Prediction project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 5.0.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/

Comment: Ok. Wanted to confirm your project name. Please also confirm that your app name is also `Diabetes_Prediction`.  Your app is the folder containing your `views.py`.

Comment: Its named "My app" and it contains another folder named "Migrations"

Comment: This is where the problem is coming from. You probably didn't read the last lines under my answer. Is it Myapp, My_app, My-app, or My app? Please look the name and tell me exactly the way it is. I doubt there'd be a space in-between. It's either a hyphen or an underscore or none

Comment: it is myapp ,,,, with no spaces

Comment: Every detail matters in programming. Please be exact with your names, uppercase, lowercase, spaces etc. Be precise. I will edit my answer shortly

Comment: I've edited my answer. Go through the whole answer again, I've added your appname `myapp`. Also read the docs.

Comment: I have applied the changes and a new error emerged the traceback is ::   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the code :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from your_appname import views # change here. 

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("", views.home),
    path("predict/", views.predict),
    path("predict/result", views.result)
```

make sure in your settings.py :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    
    #others

    # internal app
    'your_appname',     
]
```